# Looking for a particular 3d image style

Tags: 3d, stock-images

Sorry if my question is silly :-(

I'm trying to create my personal website, but I am stuck with the graphics. I tried to create pictures myself but it was too hard, so now I want to use a prepared package. What I want are some pictures like the ones below. Can anyone give the name of this style or a way of creating them?

I took the second one from newspaper :-)
[image]

[image: Man using laptop]

Comment: I'd call them 'nondescript generic overused 3D clip art"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can buy stock images like the ones above in any stock page. Here are a couple:

http://www.istockphoto.com/search/text/3d%20guy/source/basic#108c75ff

http://www.123rf.com/search.php?word=3d+guy&imgtype=0&t_word=&t_lang=en

Or you can hire someone to do customized ones for you. Or you could do them yourself using a 3d software:

http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/25-free-3d-modelling-applications-you-should-not-miss/