# What is this style of icon with 3D white people called?

Tags: icon, 3d, stock-images, style-identification

I want to know what to call this type of picture:

[image: 3D Man]

[image: 3D Man]

Is there a specific name, so that I could search these kind of images (*that is images with a white human*).
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: It's a style of stock image. I don't think there's a standard name but they often use the term "3D guy", "3D man", or "Simplified man". See more at this other question - [Looking for a particular 3D image style](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/7237/looking-for-a-particular-3d-image-style)

Comment: Searching for "Isolated 3d Figure" turns up similar images.

Answer (score 1):

You can find similar icons and images by inserting "3d icon character" in any search engine.

For example -http://www.shutterstock.com/cat.mhtml?lang=en&language=en&ref_site=photo&search_source=search_form&version=llv1&anyorall=all&safesearch=1&searchterm=3d+icon+character&site=images

Answer (score 0):

3D white people this is the real name for these guys